# How to publish module "__main__" when hosting IronPython 2.0?

Tags: c#, hosting, ironpython

I'm trying to add `[rlcompleter][1]` functionality to my fork of the [IronTextBoxControl2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/irontextbox2.aspx) in [RevitPythonShell](http://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/).

However, I'm having a hard trouble with the line:

```
import __main__
```

in `rlcompleter.py`. This is because I don't have such a module. I have been searching / sifting through the IronPython 2.0 codebase trying to figure out how to publish a module.

It seems I can do so from an instance of `IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext` with the method `PublishModule(string name, PythonModule module)`. But I'm having trouble with the following:

- obtaining a `PythonContext` instance
- obtaining a `PythonModule` instance

What I *have*, is a `ScriptEngine` and a `ScriptScope`. I'd like the scope to be published as the module `__main__`. As I understand, the scope is already attached to the module, but I can't figure out how to access it.

Here is the point in code I'd like to tie this together:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set up an IronPython environment - for interactive shell or for canned scripts
    /// </summary>
    public void SetupEnvironment(ScriptEngine engine, ScriptScope scope)
    {                        
        // add variables from Revit
        scope.SetVariable("__revit__", _commandData.Application);
        scope.SetVariable("__commandData__", _commandData);
        scope.SetVariable("__message__", _message);
        scope.SetVariable("__elements__", _elements);
        scope.SetVariable("__result__", (int)Result.Succeeded);                        

        // add preconfigures variables
        scope.SetVariable("__vars__", RevitPythonShellApplication.GetVariables());

        /* register scope as __main__ module here?! */         

        // add the search paths
        AddSearchPaths(engine);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I went through the IronPython 2.0.3 source code and came up with the following:

- a `PythonContext` is a `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LanguageContext`
- the language context of a `ScriptEngine` can be obtained through the `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Providers.HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(ScriptEngine)` method
- if you have a `ScriptEngine` for python, well, then you can just cast.

Wow. So now I finally have my `PythonContext`! So I'm going to call `CreateModule` and `PublishModule` and be home before tea!

Wait. No. First, the second argument to `CreateModule` is a `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope`. All we have is a `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope`. Which happens to contain a `Scope`, except its accessor is `internal`. So we need to do some reflection first.

Here is my sample code augmented by my proposed solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set up an IronPython environment - for interactive shell or for canned scripts
/// </summary>
public void SetupEnvironment(ScriptEngine engine, ScriptScope scriptScope)
{
    // add variables from Revit
    scriptScope.SetVariable("__revit__", _commandData.Application);
    scriptScope.SetVariable("__commandData__", _commandData);
    scriptScope.SetVariable("__message__", _message);
    scriptScope.SetVariable("__elements__", _elements);
    scriptScope.SetVariable("__result__", (int)Result.Succeeded);           

    // add preconfigures variables
    scriptScope.SetVariable("__vars__", RevitPythonShellApplication.GetVariables());

    // add the current scope as module '__main__'
    var languageContext = Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Providers.HostingHelpers.GetLanguageContext(engine);
    var pythonContext = (IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext)languageContext;
    var module = pythonContext.CreateModule(null, GetScope(scriptScope), null, IronPython.Runtime.ModuleOptions.None);            
    pythonContext.PublishModule("__main__", module);

    // add the search paths
    AddSearchPaths(engine);
}

/// <summary>
/// Be nasty and reach into the ScriptScope to get at its private '_scope' member,
/// since the accessor 'ScriptScope.Scope' was defined 'internal'.
/// </summary>
private Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope GetScope(ScriptScope scriptScope)
{
    var field = scriptScope.GetType().GetField(
        "_scope", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    return (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope) field.GetValue(scriptScope);
}
```

I kept all the namespaces in the types on purpose. I find the IronPython code kind of hard to follow and often get confused about what is defined where.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I was trying to use ScriptEngine.Execute* to run the code. Turns out using ScriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile and then calling ExecuteProgram fixes the issue.

Check out the following for the full solution: [trouble executing Selenium python unittests in C# with ScriptEngine (.NET 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664587/trouble-executing-selenium-python-unittests-in-c-with-scriptengine-net-3-5/1668431#1668431)

Note: IronPython 2.7 makes this whole thing easier:

```
public void SetupEnvironment(ScriptEngine engine, out ScriptScope scope)
{
    scope = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateModule(engine, "__main__");
    return;
}
```