# Python unittests not executing ironpython

Tags: ironpython, python-unittest

I am using ironpython 2.7. I am trying to run unittests. Following is the code,

```
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

 def test_first(self):
        self.assertEqual("hi", "hi")
 def test_second(self):
        print("Hi")
        self.assertTrue(True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

I can execute every other code but the one with unittests. I have no idea why the tests are not executing. There is no error but the result is none. Please let me know if anyone has got any idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And if you insert a failing unit test such as `self.assertTrue(False)`?

Comment: Still the result is None...

Comment: I have tried solution specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664587/trouble-executing-selenium-python-unittests-in-c-sharp-with-scriptengine-net-3/1668431#1668431 . But it did not work.